# Finding absolute path using a relative path

Tags: absolute-path

I have a relative path say *images\test\test.pdf*. This relative path is in the folder *Test*

My source is in the folder *D:\Demo\Demo1*

I have two folders in D drive- one is *Demo* and the other one is *Test*

When I use

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("\\images\\test\\test.pdf")
```

I am getting the absolute path as *D:\Demo\Demo1\images\test\test.pdf*

So I am getting an error that there is no such path. Any ideas how to point this relative path to the Test folder? I have already tried:

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("..\\images\\test\\test.pdf")

System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~\\images\\test\\test.pdf")
```

Both are not working.

Comment: do you have TEST and Demo in same folder?

Comment: Path for test and demo is

Comment: D:\Demo and D:\Test

Comment: try
..\TEST\images\test\test.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is a little long but I want to show how it works past just your situation so it can be used in a wider range of questions.

In your case a simple **`\name of your folder\file name`** will work assuming its directory is indeed in the root folder of your site folder, not the drive folder.

### **Absolute and relative pathnames**

> **Absolute, or full, path**
>
> An absolute, or full, path begins with a drive letter followed by a
> colon, such as D:
>
> **Relative path**
>
> A relative path refers to a location that is relative to a current
> directory. Relative paths make use of two special symbols, a dot (.)
> and a double-dot (..), which translate into the current directory and
> the parent directory. Double-dots are used for moving up in the
> hierarchy. A single dot represents the current directory itself.
>
> In the example directory structure below, assume you used Windows
> Explorer to navigate to D:\Data\Shapefiles\Soils. After navigating to
> this directory, a relative pathname will use D:\Data\Shapefiles\Soils
> as the current directory (until you navigate to a new directory, at
> which point the new directory becomes the current directory). The
> current directory is sometimes referred to as the root directory.

[image]

If you wanted to navigate to the Landuse directory from the current directory (Soils), you could type in the following in the Windows Explorer Address edit box:
..\Landuse

and Windows Explorer would navigate to D:\Data\Shapefiles\Landuse. A few more examples using D:\Data\Shapefiles\Landuse as the current directory are

..               (D:\Data\Shapefiles)

....            (D:\Data)

....\Final      (D:\Data\Final)

.                (D:\Data\Shapefiles\Landuse - the current directory)
...\Soils       (D:\Data\Final\Soils)

.....\Final..\Shapefiles.\Landuse  (D:\Data\Shapefiles\Landuse)

---

**NOTE:** You cannot type relative paths (using the dot and double-dot notation) in any ArcGIS application. Nor can you use relative paths in Python scripts.

**NOTE:** A relative path cannot span disk drives. For example, if your current directory is D:, you cannot use relative paths to navigate to any directory on E: